# RAILS range make reverse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
options_for_select(1920..2015)
```

Howa can get this range in reverse type, 2015..1920 doesn't work, 
I think my question is pretty understandable, but this form wants me to write more, so excuse me)))Please help

Answer (score 2):

This produces the options in reverse order:

```
options_for_select((1920..2015).to_a.reverse)

=> "<option value=\"2015\">2015</option>\n<option value=\"2014\">2014</option>\n<option value=\"2013\">2013</option>\n<option value=\"2012\">2012</option>\n<option value=\"2011\">2011</option>\n<option value=\"2010\">2010</option>\n<option value=\"2009\">2009</option>\n<option value=\"2008\">2008</option>\n<option value=\"2007\">2007</option>\n<option value=\"2006\">2006</option>\n<option value=\"2005\">2005</option>\n<option value=\"2004\">2004</option>\n<option value=\"2003\">2003</option>\n<option value=\"2002\">2002</option>\n<option value=\"2001\">2001</option>\n<option value=\"2000\">2000</option>\n<option value=\"1999\">1999</option>\n<option value=\"1998\">1998</option>\n<option value=\"1997\">1997</option>\n<option value=\"1996\">1996</option>\n<option value=\"1995\">1995</option>\n<option value=\"1994\">1994</option>\n<option value=\"1993\">1993</option>\n<option value=\"1992\">1992</option>\n<option value=\"1991\">1991</option>\n<option value=\"1990\">1990</option>\n<option value=\"1989\">1989</option>\n<option value=\"1988\">1988</option>\n<option value=\"1987\">1987</option>\n<option value=\"1986\">1986</option>\n<option value=\"1985\">1985</option>\n<option value=\"1984\">1984</option>\n<option value=\"1983\">1983</option>\n<option value=\"1982\">1982</option>\n<option value=\"1981\">1981</option>\n<option value=\"1980\">1980</option>\n<option value=\"1979\">1979</option>\n<option value=\"1978\">1978</option>\n<option value=\"1977\">1977</option>\n<option value=\"1976\">1976</option>\n<option value=\"1975\">1975</option>\n<option value=\"1974\">1974</option>\n<option value=\"1973\">1973</option>\n<option value=\"1972\">1972</option>\n<option value=\"1971\">1971</option>\n<option value=\"1970\">1970</option>\n<option value=\"1969\">1969</option>\n<option value=\"1968\">1968</option>\n<option value=\"1967\">1967</option>\n<option value=\"1966\">1966</option>\n<option value=\"1965\">1965</option>\n<option value=\"1964\">1964</option>\n<option value=\"1963\">1963</option>\n<option value=\"1962\">1962</option>\n<option value=\"1961\">1961</option>\n<option value=\"1960\">1960</option>\n<option value=\"1959\">1959</option>\n<option value=\"1958\">1958</option>\n<option value=\"1957\">1957</option>\n<option value=\"1956\">1956</option>\n<option value=\"1955\">1955</option>\n<option value=\"1954\">1954</option>\n<option value=\"1953\">1953</option>\n<option value=\"1952\">1952</option>\n<option value=\"1951\">1951</option>\n<option value=\"1950\">1950</option>\n<option value=\"1949\">1949</option>\n<option value=\"1948\">1948</option>\n<option value=\"1947\">1947</option>\n<option value=\"1946\">1946</option>\n<option value=\"1945\">1945</option>\n<option value=\"1944\">1944</option>\n<option value=\"1943\">1943</option>\n<option value=\"1942\">1942</option>\n<option value=\"1941\">1941</option>\n<option value=\"1940\">1940</option>\n<option value=\"1939\">1939</option>\n<option value=\"1938\">1938</option>\n<option value=\"1937\">1937</option>\n<option value=\"1936\">1936</option>\n<option value=\"1935\">1935</option>\n<option value=\"1934\">1934</option>\n<option value=\"1933\">1933</option>\n<option value=\"1932\">1932</option>\n<option value=\"1931\">1931</option>\n<option value=\"1930\">1930</option>\n<option value=\"1929\">1929</option>\n<option value=\"1928\">1928</option>\n<option value=\"1927\">1927</option>\n<option value=\"1926\">1926</option>\n<option value=\"1925\">1925</option>\n<option value=\"1924\">1924</option>\n<option value=\"1923\">1923</option>\n<option value=\"1922\">1922</option>\n<option value=\"1921\">1921</option>\n<option value=\"1920\">1920</option>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Reversing a range doesn't really make sense. You could use `options_for_select(2015.downto(1920))`, as `downto` returns an Enumerator which is a valid parameter for `options_for_select`.